# Ext JS textarea changes its size in Chrome when I use emptyText

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, google-chrome-devtools

I have a simple Ext JS form (4.1, but it seems reproducible in 4.2). The form contains some `textarea`s and I want to use the `emptyText` attribute on one of the textareas.  My problem is that when I use `emptyText`, the control with the `emptyText` gets slightly smaller in Chrome whenever it gets the focus and then restores its original size whenever it loses focus.  In IE9 its size always remains the same.

I can see that this style is being applied to my textarea which contains the `emptyText`:

```
.x-webkit .x-form-empty-field {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

I am not sure why this style would be required, and I'm also not sure why it would change the height of a textarea when applied, but it does.  A `textarea` that doesn't use `emptyText` has a `line-height: normal;`.

How can I eliminate this resizing?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YM5sa/

Here's the code (also in the fiddle):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {    

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top'
        },
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: 'false'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textarea',
                fieldLabel: 'One',
                name: 'one',
                width: 200
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textarea',
                fieldLabel: 'Two',
                name: 'two',
                emptyText: "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet cow jerky shank bresaola swine", 
                width: 200                  
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I addressed this by setting the `line-height` style explicitly on the `textarea`.  This seems to nicely override the `.x-webkit .x-form-empty-field`'s line-height value.

```
{
    xtype: 'textarea',
    fieldLabel: 'Two',
    name: 'two',
    emptyText: "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet cow jerky shank bresaola swine", 
    width: 200,
    fieldStyle: 'line-height: normal;'
}
```